# I want to fill a data base table from an xslt file

Tags: database, bash

I have a Table (Exchange) in my Data Base (SQL)  **Exchange(ExchangeDateStart,ExchangeDateEnd,Value,Code)**, the Period is monthly. And my csv file :

[image]

Now, my problem is how can i use this file to fill my table, i think about *Stored Procedure* or *bash script* but i used MySQlserver in the end  to import the data, but i can't do the mapping between source and destination because  i have just one DateStart and one DateEnd , in csv file i have multiple Date the same for the columns A.
To be more clear i want To show them like this

:[image]

[image]
If someone could help me plz,

Comment: You are not saying which database you are using

Comment: also, does "Script bach" mean "bash script"? You might want to correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the End i use'import data' from MySqlServerManagament in a tempory table after i update this table with a P.S [https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1179/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-database-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use Python and one of its packages that can import Excel data.

If you google "import excel data into database with python" then you'll find code that shows you how to do it.  Here's one howto with code: https://mherman.org/blog/import-data-from-excel-into-mysql-using-python/

Comment: it s gonna be  a script in python ??

Comment: The choice is up to you, You have not answered the question about what DB server you are using.

Comment: I edit my post, i start working on the script , thank u

Comment: im sorry just it didn't work for me bcq it 's not just a simple mapping to fill my table, i edit my question to be more clear , thank u

Comment: i tired but i get this error SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 19-20: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape